# Obtener datos de un Intent desde un Adapter en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, adapter

Necesito hacer algo asi `getIntent().getStringExtra("name")`desde un Adapter que asigna una personalizacion especial a una `InfoWindowAdapter` de una marcador en un mapa de mi aplicacion. Mire varias respuestas en el foro en ingles pero no pude hacer funcionar ninguna.

Les dejo el codigo de mi adapter:

```
public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "CustomInfoWindowAdapter";
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater){
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(final Marker m) {
        //Carga layout personalizado.
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.infoWindowAdapterTextView)).setText("Anduvo");

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker m) {
        return null;
    }
```

Y esto tengo en la actividad principal:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(newCustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(this));
```

**Muchas gracias de antemano.**

Comment: que quieres mostrar en el mapa, y donde tienes ese dato que quieres mostrar?

Comment: No necesito mostrar nada en el mapa, solo en el InfoWindow, que es la ventanita que aparece cuando presionas un Marcador en el mapa. Lo que necesito mostrar ahi es texto, pero la idea es que pueda conseguirlo via un Intent para procesarlo en el adapter, ya que viene de otra actividad. Gracias por comentar!

Comment: una forma seria tener la clase adapter dentro de la clase activity o fragment, para así poder llamar getActivity().getIntent().getExtras(); ...

Comment: @armen me lo podrías ejemplificar en una respuesta por favor? Desconozco como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Actividad 1 (envia datos):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Activity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("clave", "tu string");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Actividad 2 :

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
   }
   // dentro de la segunda Activity va el adapter:
   private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);

        String value1="";
        // obtienes el intent
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras !=null){
            value1 = extras.getString("clave");  
        }
         // si estas en un fragment agrega getActivity.getIntent...
```

Comment: Me devuelve: `Cannot resolve method getIntent();` , ademas no tengo el `onCreate`, es necesario? Gracias!

Comment: el ejemplo que te di son 2 activities, en la segunda activity incluyes el CustomAdapter

Comment: Es que ya lo tengo hecho así, es tal como explique en la pregunta. Por lo que se no puedo llamar a un intent desde un adapter, ya que solo funciona para las activities, entonces quiero saber alguna solucion/alternativa. Disculpa si me exprese mal, aprecio tu ayuda. Gracias!